# Weird bug accessing a vector in a struct using cython with c++

Tags: python, c++, c, struct, cython

I am using cython with a c++ compiler, and I am getting weird segmentation faults and the like.

My problems can be summed up with this code snippet:

```
from libc.stdlib cimport malloc,free
from libcpp.vector cimport vector
from libcpp.string cimport string

cdef struct vstruct:
    int a
    double b
    vector[int] v    
cpdef main():
    cdef vstruct* vptr
    vptr = <vstruct*> malloc(sizeof(vstruct))
    vptr[0].v = [1,2]
    print vptr[0].v
    print vptr[0].v

main()
```

which produces the output:

[1, 2]
[0, 0]

So, what is happening here? Does the print statement alter the vector inside of the struct? I am very confused

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`malloc` allocates but does not initialise the memory. Therefore the vector is in an underfined state when you try to assign to it and will behave unpredictably, causing a segmentation fault and unpredictable output in this case. (Exactly when and how the segmentation fault occurs is also unpredictable - in my case it seemed to be when Python was closed which probably suggests that assignment to the vector overwrote some Python internals.)

What you need to do is allocate `vptr` with the C++ operator `new` (which does initialise all the components correctly). You need to change

```
cdef struct vstruct:
```

to

```
cdef cppclass vstruct:
```

(this is to appease Cython rather than C++ - there's no real difference between structs and classes in C++ apart from their default member access).

You then change

```
vptr = <vstruct*> malloc(sizeof(vstruct))
```

to

```
vptr = new vstruct()
```

to allocate the memory while initialising all the components with their default constructors.

(You should also free it when you're done with it by using `del vptr`)

Comment: Wonderful.

I was trying to do exactly this, but Cython complained about the keyword new. I did not know about the cppclass keyword. Thank you very much.

So, when and how would malloc be used to allocate memory on the heap? Is it just not reasonable to do so with structs in cython c++?

Comment: malloc is only really OK for stuff that has a trivial constructor/destructor. Your struct would have been fine without the vector but because the vector manages memory it needs to be initialised and destroyed in a C++ way.